# VLOOKUP INSIDE A LOOP (FOR) VISUAL BASIC EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, vlookup

I have the following problem
I have a VLOOKUP that I want to run in a loop, but when vlookup doesnt find a corresponding value then it halts the script. If I handle the error with error handler, it will jump and also halt it anyway.

```
Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()
Dim filas As Integer
Dim desdefila As Integer

filas = InputBox("Cuantas files tiene éste bloque de pagos?")
desdefila = InputBox("Desde que fila empieza?")
filasfinal = filas + desdefila

For x = desdefila To filasfinal

Dim Nombre As String
Dim Rango As Range

Set Rango = Sheets(6).Range("A:B")

Nombre = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & desdefila).Value, Rango, 2, 0)
Range("E" & desdefila).Value = Nombre
desdefila = desdefila + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to go back to the loop or handling this error ?

Comment: You are declaring Nombre as a string so if the value isn't found it returns an error which Excel won't like so declare as a variant. Then add an Iferror check before proceeding.

Comment: can you also share your error handler ?

Comment: PLEASE, NO NEED TO SCREAM AT PEOPLE.

Comment: You got an answer for you rror handler answer below. For better coding (and faster) take the 3 lines `Dim Nombre As String` , 
`Dim Rango As Range` and
`Set Rango = Sheets(6).Range("A:B")` before the `For x = desdefila To filasfinal` loop, there is no need to define and set the range in your case each time you are inside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle a Vlookup error using the following structure:

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = Application.VLookup("Some Value", Range("A:B"), 2, False)

If IsError(myValue) Then
    'Code for when not found
Else
    'Code for when found
End If
```

Note that this does *not* use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, but instead uses `Application.VLookup`.

So, for your code, the error handling would be inserted to look something like:

```
Dim Nombre As Variant
Dim Rango As Range

Set Rango = Sheets(6).Range("A:B")

Nombre = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & desdefila).Value, Rango, 2, 0)

If IsError(Nombre) Then
    'Code for when not found
Else
    Range("E" & desdefila).Value = Nombre
End If

desdefila = desdefila + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The early-bound `VLookup` function from `WorksheetFunction` will raise a runtime error if the lookup fails.

If a failing lookup is an *exceptional thing* and you want to handle it cleanly, you need an error-handling subroutine:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    For ...

        Nombre = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & desdefila).Value, Rango, 2, 0)

        '...
    Next

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    ' execution jumps here in case of a failed lookup
    MsgBox "Lookup of '" & Range("A" & desdefila) & "' failed. Please verify data."
    'if you want to resume the loop, you can do this:
    Resume Next
    'otherwise execution of the procedure ends here.
End Sub
```

If you know a failing lookup is a possibility but not quite *exceptional*, and you just want to deal with it and move on, you can use `On Error Resume Next` / `On Error GoTo 0` to hide the error instead:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Nombre = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & desdefila).Value, Rango, 2, 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Nombre = "Not Available"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the late-bound version (as in [elmer007's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639270/1188513)) which extends the `Application` interface; instead of raising a VBA runtime error when lookup fails, it *returns* an *error value* that you can check with the `IsError` function:

```
Dim Nombre As Variant 'note "As Variant"

For ...

    Nombre = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & desdefila).Value, Rango, 2, 0)
    If IsError(Nombre) Then
        'handle error value
    End If

    '...

Next
```

---

One of the advantages of using the early-bound version, is that you get IntelliSense for the parameters, whereas you need to know exactly what you're doing when you use the late-bound version.